# Spring AOP java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut

Tags: java, aop, spring-aop

I want to create aspect which would intercept all methods annotatated with `MyAnnotation` and having parameter type of `MyAbstractObject` (different classes extends it and those methods having classes that extend it also should be intercepted)

```java
@Before("@annotation(mypackage.MyAnnotation) && args(mypackage.MyAbstractObject ,..)")
public void doSomething(MyAbstractObject myObject)
```

Sample methods:

```java
@MyAnnotation
public void toBeIntercepted(MyObjectExtendingMyAbstractObject x)
```

It was working with annotation only. But I had to extract parameters from jointpoint which was ugly. Now I am changing it.

This generates the following exception:

````
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:319) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:227) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.obtainPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:177) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:225) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `args()` format is incorrect.

The correct format for that pointcut expression is as follows

```java
@Before("@annotation(mypackage.MyAnnotation) && args(myObject,..)")
public void doSomething(MyAbstractObject myObject) {}
```

Comment: But the names of parameters would be different in different methods. Is it possible to base this expression on parameter types instead of parameter names?

Comment: args() designator works on matching parameter types . Parameter name matching is not possible in spring aop

Comment: The misunderstanding here is about the parameter name in the advice method. It does **not** correspond to a parameter name in any of the intercepted methods but is used in order to have a name for the argument in the advice method only.